# Move this question to Code Review or Programmers

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695421/db-constraints-business-rules-or-db-rules

I'm loathed to move it to the DBA exchange as I'll get a load of DBAs saying to move everything to the DB *(maybe...)*.

Maybe it belongs in the Code Review or Programmers exchanges?

Comment: There is no Programmers.SE anymore. The site was renamed to Software Engineering. Code Review only accepts posts about actual code, not questions about best practices. The post would be closed as too broad on Software Engineering.

Comment: You're thinking about expressing business rules through relational database constraints?  Why not eat hot coals while you're at it?

Comment: @Will No, I'm not.  I'm asking when data integrity and business rules are blurred.  Something at I would argue is the norm.  I can't really think of a data integrety rule what wouldn't fall unter the category of business rule.

Comment: Waiter, hold the coals.  Coming from a software developer perspective, we just call it a leaky abstraction and try not to think about it too much.

Comment: @Will RDD - Retirement Driven Development.  :)

Comment: consider giving a read to this guidance: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 8):

Why did you post the question on a site you think isn't appropriate and *then* ask where you should post it, instead of posting on meta first?

You also don't need anyone's help to move it, as you're the author; just delete the question and post it on another site if you want it to be on another site.

Comment: I didn't think it was in the wrong place, only asking if there was a better place.

Comment: @BanksySan It's 100% in the wrong place.  That question is certainly inappropriate on SO.  It's too broad, it's primarily opinion based, and it's not a programming problem.

Comment: I'll move it then.  Problem solved.

Comment: It's likely not on-topic on other sites in the SE network, as it's asking for opinions, which is pretty much universally off-topic (there are exceptions, but few and far between).

Answer (score 1):

*Before* you elected to move it to Software Engineering, we should've had a bit of a chat on where the question should really belong, if at all, on the network.

First, for completeness, this is the entire question.

> When we set up few tables we will probably have some relationship
>   between these rules.
>
> We can enforce these in the database, by adding constraints, or we can
>   enforce them in the application.
>
> I've never really been comfortable on what's best practice.
>
> **DB**
>
> - Faster
> - Simpler
> - Well understood
> - Pain to insert test data
> - Functionally limited to "does PK exist" constraint
>
> **Application**
>
> - *Probably* more 'correct' from a DDD perspective.
> - Has context as it's in the application domain.
> - Makes ad-hoc data inserrtion for testing easier
> - Complex rules possible
>
> What questions do you ask yourself when deciding where to enforce data
>   integraty\relationships?

The sites that you think would be more suitable - Code Review and Software Engineering (and even a rogue suggestion on SW for you to move it to Database Administrators) - have specific requirements for what questions would be good.

In my experience...

- The question isn't a good fit on Stack Overflow because there's no concrete problem to be solved.  From Stack Overflow's perspective, you're staring at a whiteboard.

  (I know that Rails/Active Record loves to blur the lines between database-enforced and application-enforced database constraints, but you've never mentioned that you were using Rails/Active Record.)
- The question isn't *exactly* a good fit on Software Engineers because it's fairly wide-open and largely depends on your application's needs.  From Software Engineer's perspective, you're asking a room of software engineers a DBA question.
- The question *might* be a better fit on Database Administrators because it does ask a pointed question about database constraints, and whether or not it makes sense to enforce those in the application or at the database level.  Further, [there is existing precedent](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/39833/37103) to suggest that, at worst, your question may be a duplicate on that site.

My recommendation to you now would be to look at the Database Administrators answer and see if it answers your question.  If it doesn't, I would encourage you to narrow down your specific question so that it doesn't potentially come across as a duplicate there, and specify what you're major confusion is.

Comment: Cheers, I have had a good read of that answer.  It's heavily from a DBA's perspective rather than from an application architecture perspective.  In my opinion the answer assumes that data integrity is a simple case of the correct keys existing.